# xampp object not found error after clicking on activation link

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I am following one tutorial for signup and sign in using email verification.
It works fine and it sends a confirmation link on provided email id. 
It shows:

I have tried adding alies as well but didn't work
I don't know how do i solve it. Please guide me.

File Structure:

```
C:.
│   
│   
│               
└───signup-email-verification
    │   class.user.php
    │   dbconfig.php
    │   fpass.php
    │   home.php
    │   index.php
    │   logout.php
    │   resetpass.php
    │   signup.php
    │   store-signup.php
    │   tbl_users.sql
    │   verify.php
    │   
    ├───bootstrap
    │   ├───css
    │   │       bootstrap-responsive.css
    │   │       bootstrap-responsive.min.css
    │   │       bootstrap.css
    │   │       bootstrap.min.css
    │   │       
    │   ├───img
    │   │       glyphicons-halflings-white.png
    │   │       glyphicons-halflings.png
    │   │       
    │   └───js
    │           bootstrap.js
    │           bootstrap.min.js
    │           jquery-1.9.1.min.js
    │           
    └───mailer
            class.phpmailer.php
            class.pop3.php
            class.smtp.php
```

I was trying to access below link

```
 localhost/drop2/signup-email-verification/store-signup.php
```

Comment: we can't tell you until you post the code

Comment: What Ravi said... l if you could provide the relevant code you are using and the link and whatever else is relevant, then we might have something to use to help you... At the moment all we can say is... That's not good is it!

Comment: @skz what is this code ?

Comment: @Ravi: Activation code

Comment: @skz yes, but what is your app folder structure and how are you trying to access. Could you post all those ?

Comment: @Ravi: I am running it on localhost. So this is the link :http://localhost/drop2/signup-email-verification/store-signup.php

Comment: post the folder structure and the file location

Comment: @Ravi: can you see it?

Comment: @skz you only need to provide structure of your file, which you are accessing

Comment: @skz where is your activation file ?

Comment: store-signup.php is the activation file

Comment: @skz always acknowledge the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you are trying to access `store-signup.php` using below URL.

```
localhost/drop2/signup-email-verification/store-signup.php
```

Now, as per above URL, your application should be `drop2` and `store-signup.php` resides under `signup-email-verification` folder. That means, you folder structure should be

```
drop2
 |
 |--- signup-email-verification
       |
       |---store-signup.php
```

As per your posted folder structure, you ***don't*** have `drop2` folder itself.

Also, you are suppose to place your project folder under your server root folder not in C: drive.